# Si "se" está dentro de los horarios de entrega

Tags: gramática

¿Por qué es "se está" en vez de "está" en el siguiente párrafo? ¡Muchas gracias!

"[Si se está dentro de los horarios de entrega, el problema inicial que uno ve a la hora de hacer un pedido online es que los tiempos de entrega «asegurados» son de 40 minutos ...](https://www.consumoteca.com/comercio/burger-king-a-domicilio/#:%7E:text=Lo%20primero%20que%20debes%20saber,00%20(dependiendo%20de%20la%20tienda))"

Answer (score 2):

Porque se trata de una [oración impersonal](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables).

> b) oraciones impersonales. Se llaman así por carecer de sujeto gramatical y en ellas la forma se precede siempre a un verbo en tercera persona del singular

En el enlace puedes encontrar información detallada y ejemplos sobre ese tipo de oraciones.

En tu contexto la frase sería más o menos equivalente a:

> Si aquel o aquellos que realizan el pedido lo hacen dentro de los horarios de entrega, el problema inicial ...

o

> Si haces el pedido dentro de los horarios de entrega, el problema inicial ...

Desde mi punto de visto tanto la frase original como mis interpretaciones son totalmente superfluas. La original incluso parece responder a un lenguaje más propio de burócratas y abogados. No tiene razón de ser porque no gestionarán ningún pedido que se haga fuera de horario. Esto es de sentido común, no es necesario indicarlo. Si eliminamos esa parte, no se pierde nada del significado.

> El problema inicial que uno ve a la hora de hacer un pedido online es que los tiempos de entrega «asegurados» son de 40 minutos, con lo cual, tu comida podrá llegarte un poco pasada a tu casa.

Incluso esta versión es demasiado verbosa, tiene muchas palabras innecesarias, incluidas por el redactor con la única finalidad de rellenar espacios. Podríamos reducir la frase a:

> Los tiempos de entrega asegurados de 40 minutos pueden hacer que la comida te llegue un poco pasada.